# Shift modifier not working on react tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, react-testing-library, vitest

I have a textarea component that is suppose to submit a form when enter is pressed without the shift modifier.

On my application, it is working properly, but the following test is returning an error.

```
it('should not submit the form when the shift key is pressed and the message is not empty', async () => {
  render(<NewMessageForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);

  const element = screen.getByRole('textbox');
  const message = 'Hello World';

  await userEvent.type(element, message);
  await userEvent.type(element, '{shift}{enter}');

  expect(onSubmit).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This is the event handler on my component.

```
const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
    // prevent the textarea from inserting a new line
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!event.currentTarget.value) return;

    customMethods.submitForm();
    methods.reset();
  }
};
```

Im using vitest as test runner.